# Strange bounce in UITableView running on iPhone 14 Pro but not iPhone 14

Tags: ios, uikit, ios-simulator

There's a strange bounce when my app is run on iPhone 14 Pro (and Pro Max) models but not any other models. How can I remove it?

The source code is here:
https://github.com/ykphuah/ListBouncePro

Refer to the video below. Left is the iPhone 14 simulator, while right is the iPhone 14 pro simulator. There's a bounce on the main listing after the sheet is dismissed.

[image]

Comment: can you remove beginUpdates() and endUpdates() method and call just reload after save and new Fetch and try it?

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar I have updated with a simple project that demonstrate the issue. Hope this makes it clearer!

Comment: I've watched the video a dozen times and I can barely see any difference. The animation on a simulator is rarely what it will look like on a real device. So many times in my own apps I've noticed view controller transitions that look terrible in the simulator but perfectly fine on my real devices. Remember, it's a simulator, not an emulator. But it might help if you go to the Simulator -> Window menu and try "Physical Size" or "Pixel Accurate". That might help.

Comment: @HangarRash the effect is real.  I have a physical 14 pro max and it is giving me the same symptoms. The animation is with low frame rate hence the effect is less obvious but it does show!

Comment: So this only happens when using Core Data?

Comment: @matt, from what I gather so far, yeah, it have to do with CoreData Update -> NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate -> refreshing the UITableView.

Comment: @PhuahYeeKeat - in `case .update:` ...  if you change **.fade** `self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)` to **.none** `self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .none)` ... does that fix the problem without adverse side-effect?

Comment: @DonMag I have updated the video with colours so it's easier to see. If I change from .fade to .none, the white colour bar will remain there!

Comment: Odd bug - worth reporting. If you really don't want that little "bounce" -- couple options: 1) present the Edit controller **Full Screen**, or 2) ***push*** the Edit controller instead of presenting it.

Comment: @PhuahYeeKeat - while this should almost certainly be considered a **bug**, it doesn't have anything to do with the use of CoreData. It appears to be related to presenting a controller with a `UINavigationBar`. Couple more options to "get around" it... 1) instead of embedding `EditController` in a `UINavigationController`, add normal Cancel and Save buttons to a standard view controller, or 2) Use a closure to `dismiss` the presented Edit controller ***before*** calling `.saveContext()` ...

Comment: @PhuahYeeKeat - I cloned your GitHub repo and added two branches with the above options: https://github.com/DonMag/ListBouncePro (Branch 1 and Branch 2, respectively).

Comment: @DonMag Can you create your solution as an answer? The reason I suspected its related to CoreData is because if I use the "Cancel" button, which doesn't save, then the issue doesn't happen.

Comment: @PhuahYeeKeat - forget my previous solutions... after more testing, none of them seems to really solve the issue. I'm posting a new answer that ***may*** be usable.

Comment: @DonMag actually the one that put code into the completion block of dismiss does work, just that it have the side effect that the data gets updated with some "delay". Your previous branch doesn't work all the time because instead of just saveContext, we need to move the update of the CoreData into the completion block as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the reason the issue **seems** to be related to `CoreData` is because this implementation causes the table view to update *while it is covered* by the presented controller.

You can easily confirm this by triggering a reload while the Edit controller is presented:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "edit") {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! EditController
            controller.isNew = false
            controller.shopping = frc?.object(at: indexPath)
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
            
            // add this to trigger a reload after 1 second (while the presented controller is still showing)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
            
        } else {
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! EditController
            controller.isNew = true
        }
    }
}
```

Now, even if you only tap "Cancel" the gap will be there.

And, you can confirm this by setting up:

[image]

With this as the entire code:

```
class NoCoreDataTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "defCell", for: indexPath)
        c.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return c
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

When run, pulling down the presented controller shows the gap:

[image]

and the gap remains after pulling it down far enough to dismiss it.

The only thing I've found that ***seems*** reliable is to implement `scrollViewDidChangeAdjustedContentInset(...)` and adjust the table view's `.contentInset.top` to "fix" the incorrect inset.

If you add this to your `ListController` class:

```
// class property
var origTopInset: CGFloat = 0

override func scrollViewDidChangeAdjustedContentInset(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if origTopInset == 0 {
        origTopInset = scrollView.adjustedContentInset.top
    }
    if scrollView.adjustedContentInset.top != origTopInset {
        scrollView.contentInset.top = -abs(origTopInset - scrollView.adjustedContentInset.top)
    }
}
```

that *should* get rid of the gap / bounce. If the app is running on a different device (such as iPhone 14 (non-Pro) from your original post), the `.adjustedContentInset.top` won't change, and so this work-around code won't adversely affect anything.

Note that I've only done cursory testing -- so thoroughly test this yourself.

---

**Edit**

The above `.adjustedContentInset.top` "fix" only works if the row updates are set to `.none` instead of `.fade`...

I've re-updated my repo clone: https://github.com/DonMag/ListBouncePro with a "Closures" branch for another approach.

I had seen cases where it still failed, but I didn't realize that Core Data calls `didChange` *when the object changes* ... such as:

```
shopping?.item = textField.text
```

I was under the impression it did not occur until:

```
appDelegate.saveContext()
```

I've re-posted my clone of your repo: https://github.com/DonMag/ListBouncePro with a "Closures" branch.

The changes are:

- instead of passing a reference to the Core Data object to the Edit controller, we pass

  - the item string (would probably be changed to a struct, assuming you'll have more than one piece of information)
  - the `indexPath` if an item was selected, or `nil` if "+" new
- Two closures - one for Save and one for Delete

All Core Data functions then take place in the List controller, which solves the "bouncing" / gap.

Now the tableView updating takes place *after* the presented controller is dismissed. That might be considered a drawback ... or maybe not. Since the data is being sorted, the user may find this easier to follow when *seeing* the update, rather than returning to a re-ordered list.

As a side note -- this may be more effort than it's worth, and may not be completely compatible with the rest of your data handling.

Frankly, the "bounce" is - to me - a non-issue. And, since this is pretty clearly a bug that will hopefully be corrected in an iOS update, any work put in to work around it would eventual be unnecessary (and maybe even counter-productive).

However, take a look at the "Closure" branch and see what you think... you might even decide that using your Edit controller **only for editing and not for actual data updating** is a better approach all around.

Comment: The bounce is still there from my testing, just that it goes from +5->0 to become 0->-5, the top row have less top padding now.

Comment: @PhuahYeeKeat - ah... that `.adjustedContentInset.top` fix only works if `.fade` is changed to `.none` .. see **Edit** to my answer.